# Unity, Moving object by friction + rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am desperately looking everywhere for a solution to this problem but did not find any possibility yet, maybe you can help me out:
I am making a simple test in which a kind of cylinder can rotate itself and moving on a flat platform by friction. I have rigid body, mesh collider attached already and a script to control the rotation. It can be moving fast or slow depends on its rotation speed.
The script is as follow:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public float rollingSpeed;
public float gravity;

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.Rotate(rollingSpeed, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0.0f, -gravity, 0.0f);
}
}
```

The problem is when I run the Play mode, this cylinder is rotating itself but staying in the same position! (in fact it is moving back and forth very slightly), I really dont know what is the cause, I tried to increase the friction parameters, add physical materials, and even adding a second force downward (like gravity) but it doesnt work. 
Can anyone please have a solution for this? Thank you guys so much!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`Rotate` is just transform eular coordinate without any force, use `AddTorque` instead for physical movement.

For example,

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * rollingSpeed * Time.deltatime);
```

Read more, [Unity Doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html).

To add a tips about basic physics on Unity.

Please remember when you are working with `Transform`, it means **NO** physics. You are just changing its position and rotation.

To work with physics, is always `Rigidbody`.

Comment: Hi Matrix, now I see it, I tried AddTorque and it works :) thank you very much.